# Hyperledger Fabric: What is the Application section in configtx.yaml?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

The [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/configtx.html) just say:

> It is recommended never to define an Application section inside of the
>   ordering system channel genesis configuration, but may be done for
>   testing.

and

> Application configuration is for channels which are designed for
>   application type transactions.

This is hardly helpful and much is left to be explained e.g.:

- what is an application type transaction?
- does the above line (It is recommended...) in the docs mean there should be no `Application` section in `configtx.yaml`? If not, what exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Application type transactions are what users would typically think of as 'normal' Fabric transactions.  For instance, invoking a chaincode, collecting endorsements, and submitting the resulting transaction to ordering.  Today (as of v1.4.0), endorser transactions are the only type of application transaction, but others will be coming in the  near future.

The non-application type transactions are internal to Fabric, and are used to coordinate channel creation.

The text is meant to convey the fact that Fabric network orchestration among the orderers (done via the orderer system channel), should not generally be exposed to participants in the network outside of the ordering service organizations.